# Php Mysql data format need to change display results without variables

Tags: php, mysql

I fetching data from mysql using php, but here issue is I need to post this data without variables. I will give clear info regarding this below please check

below is sql results i am getting from db:

```
$name = $row->name;
$phone = $row->telephone;
```

but here i need to pass this values like below

format I have to pass like this:

```
{name},{phone}
```

how should i solve this please help me.

Comment: can you tell me using str_replace only $ sign is there what about end point

Comment: Are you trying to make an array?

Comment: no i am not trying make an array, from db results i have to pass values without variable sign and field name should be in '{ }'.

Comment: Are you trying to make a JSON string?

Comment: No Jhecht, In our application sms gateway provider asking us to post vlaues in this format {name},{phone}. from db i am getting like above how should i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace).

```
$s = "{name},{phone}";
$s = str_replace("{name}", $name, $s);
$s = str_replace("{phone}", $phone, $s);
```

Comment: hi, tried but not worked. it is giving error. when i call variable $s to print it is working. if i post like this {name} no value.

Comment: I am confused; what is "post"? `echo`ing the string?

Comment: yes correct, when i print $s it is giving string name,phone values. but i need to print {name}{phone} is it possible.

Comment: Modify the original template string as you please, i.e `$s = "{name}{phone}". You need to provide example input and outputs if you want further help.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying output like that:

```
$name = $row->name;
$phone = $row->telephone;
```

and,

```
$output = '{' . $name . '},{' . $phone . '}';
echo $output;
```

Comment: I am trying to {name},{phone} like this

Comment: Above code generate as output:
`{name},{phone}`
What's wrong ?